# Angular get json array inside another array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have following JSON struncture:

```
{
  "daypart": [
    {
      "dayOrNight": [
        null,
        "N",
        "D",
        "N",
        "D",
        "N",
        "D",
        "N",
        "D",
        "N",
        "D",
        "N"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i want to do is reach keys array inside `narrative` . But whenever I try to get those keys l get forecast `undefined` or forecast `[object Object]`

Code

```
 async forcast(){
    this.http.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    .subscribe(data => {

      let f = data
      this.dforecast = f["daypart"]["narrative"]


      console.log("forecast "+ this.dforecast )


    })
  }
```

Comment: Where is "narrative" coming from? isn't it "dayOrNight"?

Comment: sorry l updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with:

```
this.dforecast = f["daypart"][0]["dayOrNight"]
```

Since it is an array.

Answer (score 3):

`f['daypart']` is an array. Thefore, you will need to reference it by its index.

```
this.dforecast = f['daypart'][0]['narrative'];
```

In addition, there is no need to declare `forcast()` as an `async` method, as we are dealing with observables, rather than Promise-based responses.

```
forcast() {
 // rest of your cose 
}
```